# checkcombobox color of the background of items

Tags: c#, wpf

I am creating application in c# and wpf.
Is there a way to make checkcombobox from this namespace xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit" with different color in every item.

[image]

I have `ObservableCollection<Item> Items` which is bind to the `checkComboBox`. In class `Item` is field: Color color, which color I want to show.

```
<xctk:CheckComboBox Name="CheckComboBox"  ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontSize="20" Margin="190,553,254,126"   />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using ObservableCollection as items source or by adding one by one ComboboxItems into your combobox.

You can modify your comboboxitem's properties.

```
ComboboxItem item = new ComboboxItem();
item.Content = "Item1";
item.Tag = "Any value"; You can assign any object and use for exemple in selection change event.
item.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
myCombobox.Items.Add(item);
```

Or

```
ObservableCollection<ComboboxItem> myList = new ObservableCollection<ComboboxItem>();

  ComboboxItem item = new ComboboxItem();
item.Content = "Item1";
item.Tag = "Any value"; You can assign any object and use for exemple in selection change event.
item.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
myList.Add(item);

myCombobox.ItemsSource = myList;
```

In this case, you can use SelectedItem in order to get the value that you need :

```
 if(myCombobox.SelectedItem != null)
  {
   var myObject = (myCombobox.SelectedItem as ComboboxItem).Tag as MyObject; //My object can be any type.
   var idValue = myObject.ID;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But now i have problem with presenting the selected value. As  content i put numbers (0,1), but when i select that it says System.windows.controls.comboboxitem

Comment: Instead of the selected value, you should use Selected item like. I modify my response.

Comment: You misunderstood me. When i selected value, (presented as a Content, example: 0 ) in the checkcombobox will not be presented just like a content, it will be written System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem: 0. Is there a way not to be seen this 'System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem:'

Comment: Depending your combobox control you should have display value member among the properties. You should leave it empty. In this case the presentation of the combobox item will be the Content Property.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the structure of xceed's `CheckComboBox`, but here is an idea should work. Frist, find out the root element that response for present the each item binded to the `CheckComboBox`. Then write a `Style` in `CheckComboBox.Resources` target to the type of that element to override its `Background` property with a `SolidBrush` that has the color in the item through a `Binding`. And if necessary, override other visual related properties like `Margin`, `HorizontalAlignment` ect. If we do that with a `ComboBox`, it should like below

```
<ComboBox ItemSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Backgournd">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding RelativeSource=
                    {RelativeSource AncestorType=ComboBoxItem},
                    Path=Content.Color}"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-1 -1"/>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Resources>
</ComboBox>
```